# JavaScript - jQuery - Is my dataSource() function safe? - How to test

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I'm new in StackOverflow and not sure whether I should ask this question here or not, so if I'm asking this question at wrong place, please let me know.

I want to implement `dataSource` in javascript (like ASP.NET). So I have created a jQuery plugin with these functions:

```
$.getUniqueString = function (prefix) {
    if (!prefix) prefix = "s";
    for (var loopIndex = 0; true; loopIndex++) {
        if (typeof window[prefix + loopIndex] != "undefined") { // if sourceId exists
            continue;
        }
        prefix = prefix + loopIndex;
        break;
    }
    return prefix;
}

$.fn.dataSource = function (source) {

    var sourceId;
    if (!source) {
        sourceId = $(this).attr("data-source-id");
        return window[sourceId];
    }

    sourceId = $.getUniqueString();
    $(this).attr("data-source-id", sourceId);
    window[sourceId] = source;
}
```

This plugin works fine. And till now, I have not faced any difficulty. Here is the link to **a working example** (fiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/Gu2KQ/

But, my questions are:

- Is my code safe enough for the client browser not to crash?
- Any suggestion to optimize this code more?
- Any other option to implement the same functionality better?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need `eval()`.  `if (typeof window[prefix + loopIndex] != undefined)` will do the same thing.

Comment: "Is my code safe enough for the client browser not to crash?" what about testing it on popular browsers and see the result? I always test stuff on firefox & explorer which is the best & the worst options for me.

Comment: [Here's a revised fiddle without any calls to `eval()`](http://jsfiddle.net/Gu2KQ/)

Comment: @Pointy - I have read that 'eval() is evil' in number of online forums but I don't know how is it an evil? What problem does it create? In fact, some javascript obfuscators use the `eval()` a number of times while minifying the js.

Comment: @epipav My firefox and IE are always updated. How can I test it on older versions of browsers? Any FREE service?

Comment: One serious problem with `eval()` is that it prevents the JavaScript runtime from optimizing your code. If a function contains `eval()`, then the optimizer will probably just not optimize the function at all (because it can't tell what's going on).

Answer (score 2):

Eval is unnecessary here. You can get and set global variables as properties of the `window` object.

```
$.getUniqueString = function (prefix) {
    if (!prefix) prefix = "s";
    for (var loopIndex = 0; true; loopIndex++) {
        if (typeof window[prefix + loopIndex] != "undefined") { // if sourceId exists
            continue;
        }
        prefix = prefix + loopIndex;
        break;
    }
    return prefix;
}

$.fn.dataSource = function (source) {

    var sourceId;
    if (!source) {
        sourceId = $(this).attr("data-source-id");
        return window[sourceId];
    }

    sourceId = $.getUniqueString();
    $(this).attr("data-source-id", sourceId);
    window[sourceId] = source;
}
```